# Is it possible to sum and unpack multiple fields in a list?

Tags: python

My code is becoming incredibly verbose in certain areas, and it would be nice if there was a more Pythonic way to accomplish the following task:

```
total1 = 0
total2 = 0
total3 = 0
for x in list:
    total1 += x.field1
    total2 += x.field2
    total3 += x.field3
```

I'm still new to Python, but I know about some tricks, like I could cut the lines I'm writing in half with...

```
total1 = sum(x.field1 for x in list)
total2 = sum(x.field2 for x in list);
total3 = sum(x.field3 for x in list);
```

but I don't want to sacrifice performance by re-iterating my lists over and over again just to save SLOC. What I'd like to do is something like this...

```
total1, total2, total3 = sum(x.field1, x.field2, x.field3 for x in list)
```

I've tried several versions of this but I keep getting syntax errors. Is there any way to do this in Python?

Comment: Not sure what `x` is, but if it is a custom class, define an `__add__` method and call `sum(your_list)` directly.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ x is just a placeholder name. in Python, you can perform operations on a list by typing, for instance `sum(x.field1 for x in list)` and it will sum the field for you. Really convenient, but now I'm trying to get it to work with multiple fields in the same list.

Comment: I'm sorry but you cannot shoehorn `sum` to return 3 outputs. Just use a loop.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ isn't there a Pythonic way, though?

Comment: Pythonic is subjective, imo.

Comment: You're overestimating the significance of making multiple passes.

Comment: @user2357112 I completely disagree. Duplicate iterations are a bad habit and can easily come back to bite you.

Comment: @Jace: [Look at these timings](http://ideone.com/a2nRN8). Up to measurement error, 3 passes are just as fast as 1. Your `sum` version is about 10% slower, probably due to genexp overhead, but using `attrgetter` erases that difference too.

Comment: @user2357112 all the same, numpy is what I needed. thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to have `sum` sum up 3 fields in parallel. This is just not possible with the current builtin. I'd recommend the best, and possibly the only option without resorting to any other libraries: a `for` loop.

```
total1 = total2 = total3 = 0

for x in your_list:
    total1 += x.field1
    total2 += x.field2
    total3 += x.field3
```

If you want to get creative, and account for an unknown number of attributes, you can use a `dict` to store your totals and `getattr` to dynamically access fields.

```
fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'] # keep in mind these are the string names of your fields
total_dict = {f : 0 for f in fields}

for x in your_list:
    for f in fields:
        total_dict[f] += getattr(x, f)
```

This is still roughly linear because the inner loop is constant in size.

---

If you want to `sum` in one line, I'm afraid this isn't possible unless you go for a number crunching library like numpy.

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.array([[x.field1, x.field2, x.field3] for x in your_list])

sum = numbers.sum(axis=0)
```

An example:

```
In [1316]: numbers = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])

In [1317]: numbers.sum(axis=0)
Out[1317]: array([3, 6, 9])
```

Comment: Well, a for loop is kind of where I am already, and the dict idea, though creative, is just as many lines of code but more complex. What I'm really looking for is a way to achieve the same result in one or two lines.

Comment: @Jace Well, you can use numpy. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Yes! Numpy was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Yup, no problemo.

Comment: @Jace: Note that proper use of NumPy is going to have a much, much greater impact on your performance than whether you make 1 or 3 passes over a list. If you're going to bring in NumPy, you might want to take some time to read up on what it offers and how to use it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` function just only return one number. Maybe you can write one function to return many numbers:

```
def my_sum(l, fields):   
  _my_sum = lambda l, f: sum(getattr(i, f) for i in l)   
  return tuple(_my_sum(l, f) for f in fields)

total1, total2, total3 = my_sum(l, ["field1", "field2", "field3"])
```

Comment: This just puts sugar on everything OP does _not_ want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're somehow opposed to using an explicit loop here and don't want to rely on additional third party libraries, you could take a functional approach and use something like [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

```
from functools import reduce
total1, total2, total3 = reduce(
    lambda x, y: (x[0]+y.field1, x[1]+y.field2, x[2]+y.field3),
    items,
    (0,0,0)
)
```